# trouble merging two json strings

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to use deep-extend ([found here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-extend)) running under express to merge a couple of objects. Note: I'm aware of the difference in structure between JSON 1 and JSON 2 - could this be the cause of my issues? Both have been created by doing a JSON.parse on a string of data. I have no control over how this data is coming to me so any advice on how to fix appreciated.

JSON 1:

```
{ '0': 
   { name: 'Car',
     level: '3',
     customname: 'Black',
     description: 'description here',
     availableForUse: true } }
```

JSON 2:

```
[ { description: 'description here',
    name: 'Car',
    availableForUse: false,
    _id: 56679b6f9754083f0fa5ce94 },
  { description: 'desc',
    name: 'Truck',
    availableForUse: false,
    _id: 5667fb8e0c85cf6d279c2af1 },
  { description: 'desc',
    name: 'Boat',
    availableForUse: false,
    _id: 5667fcc2771155032839a8db },
  { description: 'desc',
    name: 'Train',
    availableForUse: false,
    _id: 5667fd32771155032839a8dc } ]
```

What I get post merge

```
{ '0': 
   { name: 'Car',
     level: '3',
     customname: 'Black',
     description: 'description here',
     availableForUse: true } }
```

What I want

```
[ { description: 'description here',
    name: 'Car',
    customname: 'Black',
    availableForUse: true,
    _id: 56679b6f9754083f0fa5ce94 },
  { description: 'desc',
    name: 'Truck',
    availableForUse: false,
    _id: 5667fb8e0c85cf6d279c2af1 },
  { description: 'desc',
    name: 'Boat',
    availableForUse: false,
    _id: 5667fcc2771155032839a8db },
  { description: 'desc',
    name: 'Train',
    availableForUse: false,
    _id: 5667fd32771155032839a8dc } ]
```

Comment: Which is the authoritative dataset, JSON1 or JSON2? Does JSON1 overwrite all JSON2 property values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it without the use of the deep extend module.

First rearrange JSON1 so that the `name` property of each object becomes an object key:

```
var obj1 = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (p, c) {
  var o = obj[c], name = o.name;
  p[o.name] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));
  return p;
}, {});
```

OUTPUT

```
{ Car: {...} }
```

Then, loop over the array of objects. If there is an object key that matches the `name` property overwrite the properties from JSON1 to JSON2 *if they exist*.

```
for (var i = 0, l = arr1.length; i < l; i++) {
  var el = arr1[i], key = el.name;
  if (obj1[key]) {
    for (var p in el) {
     if (obj1[key][p]) el[p] = obj1[key][p];
    }
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/5q84budx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Considering the [source of deep-extend](https://github.com/unclechu/node-deep-extend/blob/master/lib/deep-extend.js), the problem is that your second argument is an array. The (mostly undocumented) API for `deep-extend` is `deep-extend(targetObject, sourceObject1, sourceObject2, ...)`. Source objects are only merged into the target if they're non-Array objects (see line 100).